# Which is faster: "SELECT * FROM table" or "SELECT x,y,q FROM table" (from a table with 4 fields)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm wondering, what is fastest (or lightest for the database to handle)

Let's say, the db table has 4 fields: x,y,z,q

I only need 3: x,y,q

What way is fastest/easiest for the database to perform (using PHP)..
"SELECT * FROM table" or "SELECT x,y,q FROM table"?

Would the same apply if the table had 5 or more fields while I still only needed to select 3?

Comment: Think by the most basic logic. You have a bag with different kinds of balls. There're people who wants to play basketball and volleyball. You can just take out the basket ball and the volley ball, and leave the rest in the bag. Or alternatively you can just empty the whole bag out, retrieve the basket ball and the volley ball to hand them out, and leave the rest laying. Which one would be easier?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SELECT x,y,z FROM table` is faster because MySQL won't have to look up what columns are in your table before executing the query.

Comment: And if those columns are indexed, it won't even need to read from the table itself...

Comment: Ok. In my head it looked easier for mysql to just select it all, instead of being specific (and getting mysql to search/sort for those fields)

Comment: It will still have to lookup the columns in order to verify that x,y,z are valid columns for that table.

Answer (score 3):

In most databases the * is slower than specifying the fields.

It's also a good programming practice to put all the columns, even though they are many.

Comment: @mowgli  It is good practice for a couple of reasons.  1) It better identifies what data you actually are using from the results of your query, 2) As `*` will retrieve the data of  all the columns, if sometime in the future someone adds 200 extra columns to your table, you suddenly will have to deal with 200 times as much data being transferred which **will** impact **your** performance, even if their work has nothing to do with your query.  Basically it is the principle of least access or least privilege (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT x,y,q FROM table` is always faster than `select *` since you are not reading all the fields but to mention `SELECT x,y,q,z FROM table` and `select *` would have same effect performance wise.